# Python logger is not loading the format

Tags: python, logging

I have the following python code:

```
import logging
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig('a.conf')
logging.debug('aaaa')
```

with the the following configuration file `a.conf`:

```
[loggers]
keys = root

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
handlers=console
level=DEBUG

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
level = DEBUG
format = generic
args = (sys.stdout,)

[formatter_generic]
format=%(levelname)s: %(name)s - %(message)s
```

The problem is however that the output of `"a.py"` is `"aaaa"` without being properly formatted with the log name or log level. Any ideas of why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [handler_console] you have "format = generic"

Change this to "formatter = generic"

This outputs:
DEBUG: root - aaaa